# gcc giving error with flex

Tags: flex-lexer

I wanted to generate executable from lex.yy so I gave following command :

```
gcc -lfl lex.yy.c
```

But it is giving error as :

```
/tmp/ccAa80My.o:lex.yy.c:(.text+0x325): undefined reference to '_yywrap'  
/tmp/ccAa80My.o:lex.yy.c:(.text+0xa7a): undefined reference to '_yywrap'
```

I can't understand reason for error. Please help me.
PS : I am using cygwin on windows 7.

Comment: try `gcc lex.yy.c -lfl` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `gcc lex.yy.c -lfl` instead. (Thought I posted this is answer, turns out it was a comment :P)